# Avoid prepending home page to URLs?

Tags: jquery-terminal

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to resolve this issue I'm having with URLs.

Within one of my commands, I'm trying to link to outside sites by doing the following:

```
this.echo('<a href="' + philip.contact[contact[0]] + '">' + contact[i] + '</a>', {raw: true});
```

Where `philip.contact[contact[0]]` is the string `"https://medium.com/"`. I get the following URL from the jquery terminal:

```
http://philipyoo.github.io/[[!;;]https://medium.com/]
```

Or I tried the following:

```
this.echo('<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">' + mylink + '</a>', {raw: true});
```

And get the following:

```
http://philipyoo.github.io/https://www.google.com]/
```

No `[[!;;]` in the url.

I saw the following [closed issue for formatting multiple param urls](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/189), but I don't really follow the conversation. I'm not formatting my URLs in any way, but I get situations where I'll get the `[[!;;]` inserted into my URLs.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's a bug, if you use raw it should not convert the urls (internaly the terminal is replacing urls by [[!;;]url] and then later it convert `[[!;;]` to links), in your second echo you didn't put http so it treat it as local url if you look at insipect the element in developer tools you will see that href is `"www.google.com"`, you can [create issue on github](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/new)

Comment: Also you can echo links using `[[!;;;;https://www.google.com]text]` but you need to download latest version of the  plugin. You have 0.9.2 which is pretty old.

Comment: @jcubic Thank you! Updating to the latest version worked. Did you want me to create an issue anyways?

Comment: no, I've fixed urls with raw option in version 0.11.20

Comment: @jcubic great, thanks again for your help and all your great work!